# Writing a shell script that run another shell script owned by other user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat, ubuntu

I have installed tomcat in /opt/tomcat6 and made one of it's instance  in ~/tomcatHost directory.The /opt/tomcat6 is owned by user tomcat and group tomcat. Unix "ls -l" produce following -

> `drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcat tomcat 4096 Dec 15 03:37 tomcat6`

In this case, to run  tomcat instance in ~/tomcatHost I need to do the following steps -

- Copy conf, webapps, logs from /opt/tomcat6 to ~/tomcatHost. Make some changes server.xml in ~tomcatHost/conf (eg- changing the port number in "Connector" element)
- give execute permission to ~/tocatHost for all user by chmod -

> `$ chmod -R 777 tomcatHost`

- and run the following commands -

> `$ export CATALINA_BASE=/home/guestUser/tomcatHost
>
>       $ su tomcat
>
>       $ cd /opt/tomcat6/bin
>
>       $ sh startup.sh`

Now the tomcat is start at the port configured in server.xml. I'm trying to write a shell script which do the task performed above. I'm new in shell scripting and can not able to solve this problem. I think there is an ownership issue, can anyone tell me how can I handle the ownership issue in shell script? Or, how can I write a script to run "startup.sh" (owned by tomcat user) from other user. Can you suggest any good tutorial for this?

Comment: You could use `sudo`.

Comment: you can try su or setuid commands.

Comment: Every time you do chmod 777, somewhere in the world a kitten dies.

Comment: This is how you give execution permission for all users: `chmod a+x file`

Comment: I guess, java tag is irrelevant here.

Comment: chmod 777 is not done every time. Sorry, I couldn't explain it properly.This step requires only the first time

Comment: java tags are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have get a solution to this. Probably it is not the best solution but it works pretty  good. I have write the following code (based on [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password)) on a file named 'start.sh' -

> ```
> export CATALINA_BASE=/home/razib/tomcat_host  
> echo "CATALINA_BASE is set..."  
> echo "Password for 'tomcat' - "  
> su -c "sh /opt/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh" -s /bin/sh tomcat
> ```

Then from terminal I just run the 'start.sh' scrip