# node.js spawn using different user

Tags: node.js, vlc, spawn

this is my code:

```
    var vlc = spawn("cvlc", [file], {uid:1000,gid:1000});
```

The program in node is executed through an instance of forever launched by root user. As cvlc does not permit to be executed as root I need it to be executed as normal user.

This is the way node.js explains how to do it: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options but does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password

Comment: How I adapt it to the structure of spawn? I mean, spawn("su",[-c "cvlc file" ',"1000"]) does not work

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try

```
var vlc = spawn("su -c cvlc -s /bin/sh otheruser"....)
```

The command string is just a string, I have no idea if the spawn function will try to parse it or not, or straight up fail.  I'm just trying to give you something to try, so give it a shot.

Comment: Oh, use exec instead of spawn.   http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: I've tried and the stderr is :  "su: must be run from a terminal"