# Run script as another user on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a Linux terminal menu by way of a simple script. Within the script it will have some commands that will submit a job (a shell script for example) as another user without password prompt.

I was able to find the following post and this worked. **[how to run script as another user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password)**
However, there was one side affect. It appears the user can run other scripts in that users folder which I don't want.

Any suggestions/help welcome.

For the sake of this. Here is what I have:

1. Username `temp1`, which is the user that will be running the menu. 
   uid=1001(temp1), gid=1001(temp1), groups=1001(temp1)
2. Username `wayne`, which is the user that the script must be submitted as to run the job
   uid=1000(wayne), gid=1000(wayne),groups=1000(wayne),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip)...
3. Script `script1.sh`, `script2.sh` owned by `wayne`.

   ```
   -rwxr-xr-x script1.sh
   -rwxr-xr-x script2.sh
   ```
4. If I try to go to `/home/wayne` as `temp1` user I get permission denied (expected)
5. I set the scripts to chmod 700 for `wayne`. So technically no one can run them other than `wayne`.
6. I have edited sudo file and have the following entry:

   ```
   temp1 ALL(wayne) NOPASSWD: /home/wayne/script1.sh
   ```
7. When I run command `su -c "/home/wayne/script1.sh" -s /bin/sh wayne` the script runs (as expected)
8. When I run command `su -c "/home/wayne/script2.sh" -s /bin/sh wayne` the script runs (not expected).

Any ideas?

Comment: One difference between your examplar question and your question is that the other question uses `user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /home/user2/bin/test.sh` but you omit the `=` in your version.  That might be all that's wrong; it might be innocent.  It's worth checking.

Comment: I made sure it had the equals and still got the same results. The output is owned by wayne so I know its running correct script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is change from su to sudo.

`su` is primarily for switching users, while `sudo` is for executing commands as other users. The `-u` flag lets you specify which user to execute the command as:

```sh
sudo -u wayne '/home/wayne/script2.sh'
```

gives `Sorry user is not allowed to execute`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: In order to run commands/scripts as another user on linux/unix you need sudo permission and run the following formula:

```
sudo -H -u <user> bash -c '<some-command>'
```

For **example**:

```
sudo -H -u wayne bash -c 'echo "user:$USER|home:$HOME|action:run_script"; ./home/wayne/script.sh'
```

from **Documentation**:

```
 sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or
 another user, as specified by the security policy.
 
-H   The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set
     the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the
     target user (root by default) as specified by the password
     database.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default
     behavior.


-u    user The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified
      command as a user other than root.  To specify a uid
      instead of a user name, use #uid.  When running commands as
      a uid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped with a
      backslash ('\').  Security policies may restrict uids to
      those listed in the password database.  The sudoers policy
      allows uids that are not in the password database as long
      as the targetpw option is not set.  Other security policies
      may not support this.
```

Answer (score 0):

don't overlook "runuser".  I found this to be just the thing I needed with python scripts run from /etc/cron.hourly

Comment: `runuser` is only available for `root`. Not only this does not answer the question, but suggesting this - using `root` as a way to run a script as another user - is a very bad idea.