# Trouble logging in user using su and expect script

Tags: bash, expect, sudo, su

I am working on making a website for a class that you log into with a username and password, and then it takes you to a page that shows your grades in the class.

The website is being run with a [bash script](https://github.com/jduga002/rapache), and will be hosted on a machine where the users already have a username and password to login.

I also have a script called `calcgrade.sh` that will calculate the grades for either the user who is currently logged in, or the user passed to the script as an argument.

So originally, I was going to use this command:

```
echo -e "$password\n" | sudo -Sk -u $user ./website/calcgrade.sh
```

to run `calcgrade.sh` as the user of the website. However, I found out that `sudo` asks for the password of the user who is *currently* logged in, not the *target* user you are trying to run a command as.

So after some reading, I found a better option would be to use `su` with an `expect` script, but I can't get it to work. Here is the code for the `expect` script (currently username and password are hard coded in for testing):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_user 0

spawn /bin/su myusername
expect "Password: "
send "mypassword"
spawn "./website/calcgrade.sh"

interact
```

When I run this script, it doesn't seem to log in the user with `su`, as it goes on to run `calcgrade.sh` with my account, rather than the user's.

Do you see what is wrong with my script? Or can you see a better way to do what I want?

Also, another problem with this method is that `calcgrade.sh` is supposed to send some output to `stderr`, but when I run it with the `expect` script, the error messages get sent to the website (the server works by sending the html for the website to `stdout`). Is there a way around this, or might it be better to have the `expect` script just check with `su` if username/password is correct, and then if so, then run `./calcgrade.sh $user` afterwards?

Comment: does this one not provide the same solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, here's the correct way to do what you want to do:

1. Give your web server user `sudo` permissions to run `./website/calcgrade.sh` as any user, without requiring a password.
2. Have the web server authenticate the user however you see fit.
3. Have it run `sudo -u someuser ./website/calcgrade.sh`, no password required.

---

Now let's look at why your approach didn't work:

It's commonly believed that `su` switches user. This is not the case. It actually starts a new shell running as another user.

This means that you can't spawn `su otheruser`, let it finish, and then afterwards spawn `calcgrade.sh`.

Instead you have to run `su otheruser`, and then send commands to the shell that `su` starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

log_user 0

spawn /bin/su someuser 
expect "Password: "
send "somepassword\n" 

# Now wait for a prompt and send the command to run
expect "$"
send "./website/calcgrade.sh\n"
interact
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. As for your suggestion for the correct way to go about it, how would you implement number 2, seeing as our web server is being built from scratch? Use `su` in an `expect` to see if the login worked?

Comment: @user3791260 If you are writing a web server using a framework, use the framework's authentication modules and configure them to validate credentials against the system's user database. How you do this depends on the framework.  If you are not using a framework, use the system's authentication libraries (e.g. libpam on Linux).