# how to run a bash script at startup with a specific user on Ubuntu 12.04 (stable)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, startup

Being fairly new to the Linux environment, and not having local resources to inquire on, I would like to ask what is the preferred method of starting a process at startup as a specific user on a Ubuntu 12.04 system. The reasoning for such a setup is that this machine(s) will be hosting an Input/Output Controller (IOC) in an industrial setting.  If the machine fails or restarts, this process must boot automatically..... everytime.

My internet searches have provided two such area's to perform this task:

```
/etc/rc.local
/etc/init.d/
```

I ask for the specific advantages and disadvantages of each approach. I'll add that some of these machines are clients and some are servers, but all need to run an IOC, and preferably in the same manner.

Within what ever method above is deemed to be the most appropriate, a bash shell script must be run as my specified user. It is my understanding all start up process are owned by root. So I question if this is the best practice:

```
sudo -u <user> start_ioc.sh
```

If this is the case, then I believe it is required to create a file under:

```
/etc/sudoers.d/
```

Using:

```
sudo visudo -f <filename>
```

Where within this file you assign the appropriate rights and paths to the user. Most of my searches has shown this as the proper format:

```
<user or group> <host or IP>=(<user or group to run as>)NOPASSWD:<list of comma separated applications>
root ALL=(user)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/start_ioc.sh
```

So for final additional information, the ultimate reason for this approach, which may also be flawed logic, is that the IOC process needs to have access to a network attached server (NAS). Allowing root access to the NAS is I believe a no-no, where the user can have the appropriate permissions assigned.

Comment: Use @reboot directive in the user's cron or make a 5 line upstart script in /etc/init/

Comment: @Williem Thanks, so I'm looking into init.d as it seems to be the most used approach.

Comment: Nb "init.d" is the old system, you likely want "init" (upstart)

Comment: @Williem Yeah, I see that... need to talk to the system designer about going to 14.04. Thanks.

Comment: upstart/init is in Ubuntu 12.04 as well. See http://superuser.com/questions/722215/upstart-run-service-as-unprivileged-user-and-pre-start-script-as-root for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but it is how I decided to complete this task:

Exactly as this post here:

[how to run script as another user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password)

I did use rc.local to initiate the process at startup. It seems to be working quite well.

Comment: Thanks for updating the hyper link.