# Switch user with sudo su command without asking password or sending password as argument

Tags: linux, sudo, su

I need to switch to another user with `sudo su -user` command but I have problems with that because it was asking me password so I type something like 
`echo mypass | sudo -S su user` and it doesn't work also.

How can I switch user without asking me password or can I send somehow password like `su user -p password`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run script as another user without password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password)

Comment: First of all, this is not a programming question; second, it's been answered 700 times on this site already, so please, just use search box.

Comment: I was searching answer in previous questions but I didn't find solution which was working for me, but I have found some kind of solution by myself. if I execute this `echo mypass | sudo -S su user` and after that `sudo su user` then it switch user without asking me password.