# How to start Jupyter Notebook on a GCP VM with predefined token automatically on VM start?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

OK I have set up jupyter notebook on a gcp VM, I want it to start automatically every time VM is started with a predefined token. (OS in Centos)

Does any one have any idea how to solve this final issue so that we can get the jupyter notebook started under the user test1 , everytime the VM starts ?

Here is what I have done so far

1. Created a local test1 user and created a Virtual env for it, installed jupyter notebook inside the virtual env for isolation of python

```
pyton3 -m venv tvenv
source tvenv\bin\activate
pip install jupyter
```

2. Understood that I would need to generate config and update token / ip / port etc inside the config becuase dynamically generated token cannot be used

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

3. modified NotebookApp.token/NotebookApp.port/NotebookApp.ip etc attributes to get that to work.
4. based on an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900350/compute-engine-startup-script-cant-execute-as-a-non-root-user) created a shell script to be added to the start up to the gcp VM

```
sudo -u test1 bash -c 'cd ~/; nohup tvenv/bin/jupyter-notebook &'
```

When i run the command manually from root it works when I update in GCP startup it constantly fails saying

```
Account or password is expired, reset your password and try again
```

Note : Helpful debugging tip. You can get the startup script logs by running below command once inside the VM

```
sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service
```

Comment: The reason you are  `password is expired` is due to passwords being disabled in Compute Engine VM images (only ssh keypairs are enabled). The startup script already runs as root. Try using `su  -u test1 bash -c 'cd ~/; nohup tvenv/bin/jupyter-notebook &' If that does not work, try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45398227/8016720)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John has already pointed out to you in the comment, sudo is not a good option, since the Startup scripts run as root, su can be used to switch to another profile.
Few other things that you should be aware of is that as you are using virtual enviornment, you have to set up similar enviornment variables as 'activate'
does.

one possible solution that you can try is below

```
 su -c 'PATH="/home/test1/tvenv/bin:$PATH";export PATH; cd ~/; nohup tvenv/bin/jupyter-notebook &' -s /bin/sh test1
```

What it does is sets the path to the virtual enviornment ( activity that is done via the activate among other tasks ) moves to home directory of the user and runs the notebook in background with test1 user profile.

I would also suggest that you use [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) in the gcp vm to [shutdown notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2844) gracefully, make sure that you replace the port with the port that you are using in your config

```
jupyter notebook stop 8888
```

Similar to start up you can check the [shutdown logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) by using the command below

```
sudo journalctl -u google-shutdown-scripts.service
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: I think this should solve my problems, I will check and let you know