# Bash script that can write and execute files only from certain directory

Tags: python, bash

I need a bash (or python) script which will edit and execute files only in a certain directory and its subdirectories but has no permissions to do so in other directories. Any ideas how to set such permissions for a script?

Comment: i guess all you need is to learn user and file permission basics.

Comment: I have found [proot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRoot) tool that acts like chroot but it does not need root privileges. Probably, this is not secure way but it can be handled enough. I have set up proot and ubuntu 10.04 (the server has 2.6 kernel) on server where I do not have root access. It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

the Apache webserver does a similar thing by creating its own user on linux, i.e. the user *apache* can access `/var/www`  without being root :

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/how-to-add-linux-user-with-document-root-permissions/

so you can create a new user and give this user only permissions for the particular directory

then any other user who needs to use the script can run it as the user you created :

https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

[how to run script as another user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password)

Comment: Thank you for a good idea but I need to run such script on a server where I don't have root access so I can't create a user. Thus, solutions that are based on user access seem to be not proper.

Comment: beside using `owner` in the linux permissions is only possible `group` https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions however in this case (  create a group,... ) you also need root access on the server. it is not possible to allow a script to be executed only in a specific directory because there is simply no programmatical mechanism, i.e. flags that are attached to the file that contains the script , in linux any access security is regulated by the permissions